# Parenthesizing a string so that expression takes a given value

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, parentheses, boolean-expression

The following problem is from the chapter on Dynamic Programming by Vazirani et. al.

> [6.6]Let us define a multiplication operation(×) on three symbols a; b; c according to the following table:
>
> [image: Multiplication table]
>
> Therefore, a × a = b , a × b = b etc.
>
> Find an efficient algorithm that examines a string of these symbols, say `bbbbac`, and decides
> whether or not it is possible to parenthesize the string in such a way
> that the value of the resulting expression is `a`. For example, on input `bbbbac` your algorithm should return **yes** because `((b(bb))(ba))c = a`.

#### Here is my approach:

Map it to the problem of counting the number of boolean parenthesizations as given **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6701812/counting-boolean-parenthesizations-implementation)**. In that problem, you are given a boolean expression of the form

T *or* F *and* T *xor* T

and you need to find the number of ways of parenthesizing this so that it evaluates to true.

We can think of *or* , *and* , *xor* as operators which follow certain rules (T *xor* F = T etc.) and act on operands taking values T or F.

For our original problem, we can think of a,b,c as operands with multiplication(x) *as defined by the given table* as providing the rules.

Does the above approach make sense or is there a simpler approach ?

Comment: If it's from a chapter on dynamic programming.. you should try using dynamic programming.

Comment: @Nabb: The boolean parenthesization problem I mention already has a dynamic programming formulation. My question contains the link to the SO question which shows the DP formulation.

Comment: You cannot map this problem to the boolean parenthesizations problem. What you can do is adapt a specific algorithm (like the one shown in the answer) that does not really use the boolean nature of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your approach should be similar to the problem you mentioned. In general, if there are ***n*** symbols (instead of 3 as you mentioned in this problem or 2 as in the problem you've given link to), what you should do something like this -

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXL 500
#define MAXN 100

int     isPossible[MAXL][MAXL][MAXN];
int     matrix[MAXN][MAXN]; //multiplication table
char    str[MAXN+1];
int     L;

int go(int start, int end, int need) {
    if(start > end) return 0;
    if(isPossible[start][end][need] != -1) return isPossible[start][end][need];

    int i,x,y;
    for(i = start; i < end; i++) {
        for(x = 0; x < MAXN; x++) {//you can optimize these x & y loops by pre-determining which combinations can give you 'need'
            for(y = 0; y < MAXN; y++) if(matrix[x][y] == need) {
                if(go(start, i, x)==1 && go(i+1, end, y)==1 ) {
                    isPossible[start][end][need] = 1;
                    return 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    while(scanf(" %s",str)==1) {
        L = strlen(str);
        memset(isPossible, -1, sizeof(isPossible));
        go(0, L-1, 'a');
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Note that, this is not a tested and complete source code.

Comment: You never assign `isPossible[start][end][need] = 0`, so if there is no solution, you will test the same substrings over and over again.

Answer (score 0):

We can solve this problem by Dynamic programming  [pseudo-Algorithm](http://web.cs.wpi.edu/~sms/cs584/Problems9.pdf) can be found here.

```
/**
* Parenthesizing a string so that expression takes a given value
*/
import java.util.*;
class Solution
{
static boolean func(int[][] matrix, int[] str, int n, int symbol)
{
    Set<Integer>[][] T = new Set[n][n];

    // Assign the value
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        T[i][i] = new HashSet<Integer>();
        T[i][i].add(str[i]);
    }


     for(int gap = 1; gap<n; gap++)
     {
         for( int i = 0, j = gap; j<n; i++, j++)
         {       
             T[i][j] =  new HashSet<Integer>();

             for(int k=i; k < i+gap; k++)
             {
                 Iterator<Integer> outer = T[i][k].iterator();
                 while(outer.hasNext())
                 {
                     int elementOuter = outer.next();
                     Iterator<Integer> inner = T[k+1][j].iterator();
                     while(inner.hasNext())
                     {
                         int elementInner = inner.next();
                         int val = matrix[elementOuter][elementInner];
                         T[i][j].add(val);
                     }
                 }
             }
         }

     }
     if(T[0][n-1].contains(symbol))
         return true;
     return false;
}


public static void main(String args[] ) throws Exception 
{
    int[] stringNew = {1, 1, 1, 1, 0}; // for String "bbbbac"
    int element = 3;
    /**
     * Here a -> 0       
     *      b -> 1
     *      c -> 2
     *      
     *      Table                  Equivalent Table
     *      * a b c         \      * 0 1 2
     *      a b b a    ------\     0 1 1 0
     *      b c b a    ------/     1 2 1 0
     *      c a c c         /      2 0 2 2
     */
    int     matrix[][] = {{1, 1, 0},{2, 1, 0},{0, 2, 2}}; //multiplication table

    System.out.println(func(matrix, stringNew, stringNew.length, 0));
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Specifically for the product rules given in the question, I tried to find patterns in inputs that give a solution, but then soon found that is easier to find patterns in inputs that do not have a solution. For instance: `b*` or `c*` or even `c*b*` do not allow a solution. Looking at inputs of 3 long, then of 4 long, then of 5 long, I could derive this regex pattern for inputs that do not have a solution:

```
^(c*([ab]?a?a?b+)?|(aa|b|c*a)c*a|bac*(ab)?b*)$
```

So there are essentially three alternative patterns here:

```
c*([ab]?a?a?b+)?
(aa|b|c*a)c*a
bac*(ab)?b*
```

I tested this for all possible inputs with up to 10 characters, and no new patterns emerged.

This regex will test any input in linear time.

#### Divide and conquer

For the general case (and for testing the above regex solution), you could use a kind of divide-and-conquer approach in combination with memoization (dynamic programming).

You could actually store the strings -- that have the parentheses -- for a solution for a given range.

As for sub ranges you don't know what the desired outcome is, you could continue until you have a solution for any possible outcome (and then stop) or continue until all partitionings have been checked. The caller will thus get for every possible outcome a solution (a non-empty, parenthesised string), or none (empty string).

Here is that idea implemented in an interactive JavaScript snippet (which can easily take a different multiplication matrix). Enter the input, and a solution will appear immediately if there is one. The input size is limited to 28 characters, as for longer inputs the process takes too much time to be pleasant to work with.

The snippet also includes the regex-based check:

```js
const a = 0, b = 1, c = 2;

const mul = [
    [b, b, a],
    [c, b, a],
    [a, c, c]
];

function solve(str, outcome) {
    // Convert input letters to numbers (a -> 0, b -> 1, ...etc)
    const expr = Array.from(str.toLowerCase(), ch => ch.charCodeAt() - "a".charCodeAt());
    const memo = new Map;
    
    function recur(start, end) {
        let key = start * str.length + end; // unique identifier for the range (start, end)
        let solution = memo.get(key); // retrieve from memoization
        if (!solution) {  // Not memoized yet
            solution = Array(mul.length).fill("");  // Start by indicating it is not possible to get any outcome
            if (start + 1 === end) {  // base case with one value
                solution[expr[start]] = str[start];
            } else if (start + 2 === end) {  // base case with two values
                solution[mul[expr[start]][expr[start+1]]] = "(" + str.slice(start, end) + ")";
            } else {   // Case for which recursion will be used
                let unsolvedCount = mul.length;
                // Split expression at any possible point
                for (let split = start + 1; split < end; split++) {
                    const left = recur(start, split);
                    const right = recur(split, end);
                    for (const leftRes in mul) {
                        if (left[leftRes]) {  // For every possible solution at the left
                            for (const rightRes in mul) {
                                if (right[rightRes]) {  // ... and every possible solution at the right
                                    const product = mul[leftRes][rightRes]; // ... perform the product
                                    if (!solution[product]) {  // We didn't have this outcome yet
                                        solution[product] = "(" + left[leftRes] + right[rightRes] + ")";
                                        // Allow for quick exit when for all possible outcomes we have a solution
                                        unsolvedCount--;
                                        if (unsolvedCount === 0) return solution;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            memo.set(key, solution); // Remember the work done for this range
        }
        return solution;
    }
    // Get the solution for the wanted outcome and remove the outermost parentheses, if any.
    // An empty string means there is no solution with that outcome
    return recur(0, expr.length)[outcome].replace(/^\(|\)$/g, "");
}

const regex = /^(c*([ab]?a?a?b+)?|(aa|b|c*a)c*a|bac*(ab)?b*)$/;

// I/O handling:

let input = document.querySelector("input");
let outputs = document.querySelectorAll("span");

input.addEventListener("input", refresh);

function refresh() {
    let str = input.value;
    if (!/^[abc]*$/.test(str)) {
        outputs[0].textContent = "Invalid input";
        outputs[1].textContent = "";
        return;
    }
    let solution = solve(str, a);
    outputs[0].textContent = solution || "No solution";
    let decision = !regex.test(str);
    outputs[1].textContent = decision ? "There is a solution" : "No solution";
}
```

```html
Input: <input size="28" maxlength="28"><br>
Solution: <span></span><br>
Regex:  <span></span>
```